# Migrating a friends website to a new host. What wordpress files are most likely to cause a redirect?

Tags: php, wordpress, web, migration

I'm migrating a wordpress website from SwellHost to HostGator. Since they both use cPanel I simply made a full back up of the original and had HostGator restore the backup to the new server.

Initially, when trying to access the website through the new servers IP, it would throw a permissions error; that was a plugin issue and I fixed it by modifying the plugin config file. (It was Digital Access Pass)

Everything seems to be great now, but whenever I try to access the site through the IP it redirects me to the domain name, which is still under the old host.

Does anyone have any idea of what wordpress files may be forcing the redirect?

Comment: `.htaccess` would be my guess

Comment: I've removed every thing but the bare bones in the htaccess, but it still redirects every time. What would be the best way to check which server it's pullling information from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress' internal configuration will redirect any call to its home page to the addresses specified by the siteurl and home options stored in the options table in the database.

You will either want to manually edit these settings in the database to stop the Site redirecting from the IP address to the live site, or as a temporary way to test you can edit your systems host file to override the DNS and point the domain to the new IP address, as explained [here](https://wpengine.com/support/emulate-dns-change-with-the-hosts-file-trick/)

Answer (score 0):

**If the domain isn't the same**, have you [do this (Codex:Moving_WordPress)](https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress) ? (you can use Search-Replace-DB by interconnectit script for migrate domain)

**If the domain are the same**, maybe the DNS route domain to the old IP Serveur, so you must change DNS configuration.

In this case, while the DNS changement is not good, you can temporarily access to the new serveur without changing anything in DB or Wordpress configuration. Simply by editing your local hosts file. [Read this tutorial](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27350/beginner-geek-how-to-edit-your-hosts-file/) to know how-to edit this file.